# Find nearest Date in past

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a `Service` class. One of the fields is a collection of `ServicePrice` objects, which have a `Price` and `СhangeDate` field.

```cs
class Service 
{
    ObservableCollection<ServicePrice> ServicePrices {get; set;}
    // other fields
}

class ServicePrice 
{
    int Price {get;set;}
    DateTime ChangeDate {get;set;}
}
```

I need method to find the price of a service that was relevant at some point in time.

```cs
 public int? GetPriceAtDate(DateTime date)
{
    // Do something here
    int? ActualPrice = 0 
    return ActualPrice;
}
```

I was finding a solution using the LINQ MinBy function:

```
 public int? GetPriceAtDate(DateTime date)
{
    return ServicePrices.MinBy(sp => (sp.ChangeDate - date).Duration()).Price;
}
```

But this function will return the nearest date, but not necessarily from the past. It would be quite strange to get a price for a product from the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would handle this in two phases:

- Filter out everything in the future (with respect to `date`)
- Find the latest remaining change date

```cs
public int? GetPriceAtDate(DateTime date) =>
    ServicePrices
        .Where(sp => sp.ChangeDate <= date)
        .MaxBy(sp => sp.ChangeDate)?.Price;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! This is really what I needed. However, I had to edit a little so that there were no errors: `ServicePrices.Where(sp => sp.ChangeDate <= date)?.MaxBy(sp => sp.ChangeDate)?.Price`. The function will return `null` if a date was specified before any of the prices were set.

Comment: @Mideks: You definitely don't need it after `Where`, as that will return an *empty* sequence if there's no match. I'll fix the `?.Price` at the end though.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it turned out to be unnecessary. Thanks for the corrections! Have a nice day.